# How to validate JSONs from another maven modules from same parent

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, architecture

I want to write a unit test that validates all JSON files from all dependent modules,
My Maven project structure is as follow,

```
Parent A - 
          module 1 - /resources/a.json
          module 2 - /resources/a.json
          .
          .
          .
          module test - which reads the a.json from all parallel modules and validates.
```

Also, Ideally, my test code should not update after the new module added to the parent. only I should add a new dependency (of the newly added module) in the test module.

Can it be possible with some JUnit or Maven feature or plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First the resource should either be in `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`. The question is also: Is that resource used in a test or should be part of the production code? If so I would write a test (separate module) which is called in each module... and would ask why two different modules have the same file? (or at least the same name?) ...

Comment: Thanks, @khmarbaise, we need the same JSON file name because then it will be easy to ready in production, I can write a common test which can be called in each module but in that case, in every new module, I need to write the test.

Comment: This puzzles me more. What are going to test with such a test? That your code which reads JSON works? Should be done only once?